# Full-text search on a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2019 and want to run a full-text search like below.
It takes a few minutes to get result set.
The Text columnn is nvarchar with 'Full-Text Indexing Enabled' set to True.
The NoteText does not have an index on Text column. I tried it with FREETEXT and still runs slow.  Is there a better solution?
I would appreciate any feedback.

```sql
Select distinct
txt.NoteKey
from NoteText AS txt
where (CONTAINS(txt.Text, '("Red")') or 
       CONTAINS(txt.Text, '("Blue")') or
       CONTAINS(txt.Text, '("White")') or
       CONTAINS(txt.Text, '("Blue and white")') or
       CONTAINS(txt.Text, '("Colors")')
```

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` return? How did you set up the index?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` won't return anything on SQL Server - except a syntax error :) but I assume that displays the execution plan which would indeed be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried executing just one full-text search instead of five? i.e.: `... WHERE CONTAINS(txt.Text, '"Red" OR "Blue" OR "White" OR "Blue and white" OR "Colors"')`

Comment: The search term should be supplied as nvarchar. Have you tried a REORGANIZE on the catalog?